# Best way to edit a JPG in Photoshop

Tags: jpeg, photoshop, lossless

I want to edit alot of camera photos (captures in JPG format) to correct exposure (and sometimes framing and other) issues, but want to minimise any loss of quality when I re-save the file. Is the best way to open each image as Camera Raw, make the adjustments, then use "Save Image" from the Camera Raw screen to save my changes? 
I notice that this results in a smaller file size than the original (e.g. 1.95Mb vs 3.75Mb), but wanted to be sure that I was using the optimal method for opening/editing/saving so as not to lose too much image quality.

Comment: This question does not seem to be on-topic according to the [guidelines of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: Adobe Camera Raw is for RAW files (and TIF). If you want to retain all the quality that is in your original JPEGs, save your processed files as PSD files.

Answer (score 0):

The way to minimize data loss when editing a JPEG is to resave using the same sampling and quantization tables as the original.

My guess the way to do that in Photoshop is to save in a lossless format (e.g., PNG) then converge to JPEG using some command line application that will allow you to specify the sampling and quantization tables.

Comment: That sounds like a good approach. Would you know of any examples of command line utilities that will do this sort of conversion?

Comment: I believe you can do this with ImageMagick using a separate file defining the tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading them to a website then you can go File>Open (navigate to your file and open it) then make your changes and then go File>Save For Web. If you are not uploading these or trying to get a smaller file size then just use the normal save (File>Save (Or Save As)) the only time I would use Camera Raw is if I was editing a photo in a .raw file, as in directly from a camera. Even if I where to edit a raw file I would take it through Lightroom and make it a PNG (Highest quality, decent size) then go into Photoshop and open it with File>Open.